# How does --contract-whitelist and --actor-whitelist work for nodeos?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, eosio.system, producers

Does the `--actor-whitelist` and `--contract-whitelist` work in the sense that if the list is set for that block producer that only those actors can perform transaction and only those contracts may be used for transaction purposes?

My goal is create a contract whitelist and only whitelist system contracts and other approved contracts to prevent all other contracts from being callable.

There would be a whitelisting process for all active block producers to update their config.ini files so that the new contract can be used.

```
  --actor-whitelist arg                 Account added to actor whitelist (may 
                                        specify multiple times)
  --actor-blacklist arg                 Account added to actor blacklist (may 
                                        specify multiple times)
  --contract-whitelist arg              Contract account added to contract 
                                        whitelist (may specify multiple times)
  --contract-blacklist arg              Contract account added to contract 
                                        blacklist (may specify multiple times)
  --action-blacklist arg                Action (in the form code::action) added
                                        to action blacklist (may specify 
                                        multiple times)
  --key-blacklist arg                   Public key added to blacklist of keys 
                                        that should not be included in 
                                        authorities (may specify multiple 
                                        times)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `--contract-whitelist` works is that if the current producer has that contract whitelisted, it can perform actions.  All other contracts are considered blacklisted.

I would assume all of the flags would work the same way.  Unsure how it would work if multiple flags were used together.